# C/C++ BEGINNER - fgets with stdin causing unexpected 'loop' results

Tags: c, netbeans, fgets

I'm a programming student who's only really looked at Java up until now. This semester is our first time using C and I'm having a lot of trouble wrapping my head around some of the simplest functions. I really have no idea what I'm doing. I couldn't even get Eclipse to work correctly with MinGW so I eventually gave up and reverted to Netbeans.

So basically I'm trying to use fgets to read user input for a switch-case menu, but I can't get fgets to work in even the simplest situations. To troubleshoot I tried copying a simple fgets example from online, but even that is giving me unexpected results.

When I run the code below it just runs an infinite empty loop (it does not prompt for user entry at all, it does not accept any user entry, it just 'runs' forever and the console remains blank). When I delete the fgets line and remove the other reference to the 'name' variable it works as you would expect (prints the user entry prompt and then ends).

Example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  char name[10];
  printf("Who are you? ");
  fgets(name,10,stdin);
  printf("Glad to meet you, %s.\n",name);
  return(0);

return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

}

Any advice would be appreciated!

Other info:
I am running - Win 8 (poor me) & Netbeans IDE 8.0 (with MinGW)

When creating my C project I select File=> New Project=> C/C++=> C/C++ Application

EDIT: When I run the program I have tried: 
1) right clicking the project file => Run; and 
2) clicking the big green arrow in the netbeans ribbon;
.... neither works.

Comment: add a '\n' after the format string in `printf("Who are you? ");` (stdout is line buffered)

Comment: The above works perfectly for me, maybe compiler difference? Using visual studio 2013

Comment: The problem is probably in how you run the code. You should add that information. E.g "I select the Project => Run" menu item

Answer (score 0):

This code should work, but for you to be able to input anything, you need to run in in a proper terminal.

My guess is that you're running it inside your IDE and it's set to use pipes as stdin/stdout. Instead you should start `cmd.exe` and run the program in there (you'll have to navigate to the correct directory first).

Or, optionally, there might be a setting in your IDE to run the program using `cmd.exe` or with a builtin terminal.

A final note. You should learn to use `sizeof` whenever a buffer size is required. I.e. change this:

```
 fgets(name,10,stdin);
```

to

```
 fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);
```

Also, please use spaces to make your code more readable. Reading code is a big part of programming.

Comment: I managed to run it in cmd.exe. I've never had to do it that way before and it seems a little over the top. Shouldn't netbeans be designed to handle this itself?

Comment: Yeah, most IDEs do. NetBeans seem to be designed primarily for GUI programming so perhaps that's why. There might be a setting for it?

Answer (score 0):

1) You might want to flush the file, after printf("Who are you? "); with fflush(stdout);

2) You have two return statements (which is harmless).

Other than that, your code is fine.

Comment: This seems to have helped a little, in that now it prints the "Who are you? ", but when I type my name it doesn't show the text as I type and it doesn't end until I have entered ten characters (even after changing fgets(name,10,stdin); to  fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);)

Answer (score 0):

It works perfect - but you might want using `fflush(stdin);` before the `fgets()` call.
Also remember fgets return a string with '\n' after a user input - solved simply with `name[strlen(name)-1]='\0';` - which is basically putting NULL as an "end of a string" symbol, basically you remove the '\n'.
And DO NOT change `10` to `sizeof(name)` - it doesn't matter at all, basically it's even supposedly worse as you can't use this in functions properly (sizeof(name) won't always match the length and would be the size of the pointer).
You should try compiling with MinGW if it didn't work, it will surely work on it.
A reminder: `fgets()` may let you enter MILLION characters, but it will take the first 10, in this case, at least.